# Bootstrap3 cols not filling space of row in IE8

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My bootstrap columns are not filling the entire width of the row in IE8... The second col-sm-6 comes short on the right hand side. I am using respond and html5shiv already. Any ideas? My code is below.

```
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-6">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: Post your Html5shiv and respond code.

Comment: I have included both respond and html5 shiv as plugins. Here are links to both if that helps? Thanks

https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv.js
https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/src/respond.js

Comment: I would suggest creating a sample on jsfiddle.net, or codepen.io, but those sites don't work with IE 8.  I'd suggest just not using IE 8 at all.  Tell your clients/boss to upgrade their browser, or if they can't, then switch to another browser.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: My bootstrap-ie7.css was interfering with my columns. Once I delete this, all started working nicely on IE8.